# Return a single value using GUID

Tags: sql, t-sql

The goal of my query is to return a single value depending on if column `F39` is empty (null) or or the date is "bigger or equals today"

As a unique ID I have `XPARG` which is a `GUID`.

```
SELECT XPARG,XPARTBL,F38,F39 FROM T_TRANS1309 
WHERE T_TRANS1309.XPARG = N'b2365922-cb63-f976-4c1c-ccd50443b4d4'  AND T_TRANS1309.F39 IS NULL OR T_TRANS1309.F39 >= CONVERT(NVARCHAR,getdate() ,102)
```

Somehow my query returns always more then one value with GUID's that are not the one requested. I can't figure it out why.

Comment: Why are you comparing dates using `NVARCHAR`? `F39` should be `DATE` or `DATETIME` if it contains dates. Also careful with the `AND/OR` precedence. You want to wrap the `OR` conditions with parenthesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an operator precedence issue, `AND` is higher than `OR` so your query is effectively:

```
SELECT XPARG,XPARTBL,F38,F39 FROM T_TRANS1309 
WHERE (T_TRANS1309.XPARG = N'b2365922-cb63-f976-4c1c-ccd50443b4d4'  AND T_TRANS1309.F39 IS NULL) OR T_TRANS1309.F39 >= CONVERT(NVARCHAR,getdate() ,102)
```

which means it is also selecting any row which has a date >= today. What you want is:

```
SELECT XPARG,XPARTBL,F38,F39 FROM T_TRANS1309 
WHERE T_TRANS1309.XPARG = N'b2365922-cb63-f976-4c1c-ccd50443b4d4'  AND (T_TRANS1309.F39 IS NULL OR T_TRANS1309.F39 >= CONVERT(NVARCHAR,getdate() ,102))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input you are absolutely right fml i am blind sometimes ..